# Dropdown List value not updated after changing selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using a dropdownlist which allows the user to choose a value (representing a client name.) I'm binding that list in the Page_Load doing it like that :

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    var airClients = (from ac in db.AIR_CLIENTS orderby ac.CLIENT select ac.CLIENT).ToList();

    ddlClients.DataSource = airClients;
    ddlClients.DataBind();
}
```

If I'm reaching my Edit view (with all the fields filled, including that dropdownlist), I can change the client by selecting another one in the list. However, when I'm saving, the new selected value is not taken into account. I'm trying to get it by doing that :

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();

        if (Session["id"] != null)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"].ToString());
            SIMULATION simulation = (from s in db.SIMULATION where s.SIMULATION_ID == id select s).FirstOrDefault();
            string client = ddlClients.SelectedItem.Text;
            AIR_CLIENTS currentClient = (from ac in db.AIR_CLIENTS where ac.CLIENT == client select ac).FirstOrDefault();
            int monthNego = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonthNegotiation.SelectedItem.Text);
            int roundNego = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoundNegotiation.SelectedItem.Text);
            simulation.SIMULATION_NAME = mmDesc.Text;
            simulation.SIMULATION_TYPE = ddlSimulationType.SelectedItem.Text;
            simulation.CLIENT_ID = currentClient.CLIENT_ID;
            simulation.SIM_START_DATE = dteStart.Date;
            simulation.SIM_END_DATE = dteEnd.Date;
            simulation.CONTRACT_YEAR = ddlContractYear.SelectedItem.Text;
            simulation.MONTH_OF_NEGOTIATION = monthNego;
            simulation.ROUND_OF_NEGOTIATION = roundNego;

            db.SaveChanges();

            Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

So in order to have a clear idea of what I want to say, if in my Edit View I've got "Apple" as the original value and I want to change it by selecting "Amazon", when I'm debugging I still see "Apple" as the selected value.

I can't figure out where I should fix the code to make it work. Any idea?

EDIT : ASPX dropdownlist code

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" ID="ddlClients" ClientInstanceName="ddlClients"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

I'm using the DevExpress library but I think it isn't reliable.

Comment: Can you post the aspx code of dropdown list.

Comment: Why you use `Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");` at the end of your function ?

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil to redirect my user to the main page after the update...